# Check if first argument is a valid number consisting of only decimal digits

Tags: c, cs50

This is the code I'm trying to use for the "validating the key" part to try to return success only when the argument is a digit. However, when I run my program, some numbers are considered wrong. I don't understand why.

```
~/pset2/caesar/ $ ./caesar 9
Usage: ./caesar key
~/pset2/caesar/ $ ./caesar 45
Success
45
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (argc == 2 && isdigit(argv[1][n])) {
    printf("Success\n%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
  }
```

Comment: Please format your code in a readable manner.

Comment: You need do the check for each `argv[1][i]` with `i` varying from 0 to `strlen(argv[1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proper way to validate such inputs is to use `strspn` and check it ate the whole string. In almost all cases `strspn` will be faster than any hand-coded version, unless maybe if you combine validation and conversion.

Here's your code with a validation function doing exactly that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

int validate_arg(const char *s) {
  size_t len;
  len = strspn(s, "0123456789");
  return len > 0 && !s[len];
}

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  int n = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (argc == 2 && validate_arg(argv[1])) {
    printf("Success\n%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
  } else {
    printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Side-note: It would be better to use an unsigned type and convert the number using `strtoul`.

Comment: Calling `atoi(argv[1]);` before `if (argc == 2 ...` does not properly check for sufficient arguments.  Good use of `strspn()`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't correct the other aspects, just the validation.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is here:

```
if (argc == 2 && isdigit(argv[1][n])) {
```

This line does not make sense, you are checking if the n-th character of the first argument is a digit, but (1) you don't even know if the first argument has enough characters (`n` is returned by `atoi` so it could be arbitrarily large) and (2) you're not checking *all digits* of the argument.

---

If you want to check that every single character in the first argument given to your program is a digit you can do so in two ways:

1. Iterate over each character and check with `isdigit()`:

   ```c
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <ctype.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       char *c;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fputs("Usage: ./prog <key>\n", stderr);
           return 1;
       }

       for (c = argv[1]; *c != '\0'; c++) {
           if (!isdigit(*c)) {
               fputs("Usage: ./prog <key>\n", stderr);
               return 1;
           }
       }

       printf("Success!\n%s\n", argv[1]);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. Use a function like [`strtol`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) (***not `atoi`***, since it does not signal errors). Using `strtol` also has the benefit of automatically checking for you if the number is in range of the values that can be stored in a `long` (if not, `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` is returned and `errno` is set appropriately).

   ```c
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <errno.h>
   #include <limits.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv) {
       long num;
       char *endp;

       if (argc != 2) {
           fputs("Usage: ./prog <key>\n", stderr);
           return 1;
       }

       errno = 0;
       num = strtol(argv[1], &endp, 10);

       if (endp == argv[1] || *endp != '\0' || errno == ERANGE) {
           fputs("Usage: ./prog <key>\n", stderr);
           return 1;
       }

       printf("Success!\n%ld\n", num);
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Option 2 has the advantage of already converting the number for you, so I would suggest that over option 1. **NOTE THAT** `strtol` can return a negative value if the given string starts with `-` (e.g. `-123`): you might want to check for that if you don't allow negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> when I run my program, some numbers are considered wrong.

With an input argument like `"123"`, the below code attempts to check if the 123rd character of the 3 character argument is a digit.  Access of `argv[1]` outside `"123"` is *undefined behavior* (UB) - bad.

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
if (... isdigit(argv[1][n])) ...  // UB
```

---

To test if input is all digits:

1. Check for the expected number of arguments *before* using `argv[1]`.
2. Test each character of string `argv[1][]`.

Sample

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
  if (argc == 2) { 
    const char *digit = argv[1];
    while (*digit >= '0' && *digit <= '9') {
      digit++;
    }
    // If code reached the end of the string?
    if (*digit == '\0') {
      printf("Success\n%s\n", argv[1]);
      return 0;
    }
  }
  printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
  return 1;
}
```

---

Code could alternatively use `isdigit()` which is best called with `unsigned char` values:

```
    const unsigned char *digit = argv[1];
    while (isdigit(*digit)) {
      digit++;
    }
```